# RequireJS define Browser Race Condition

Tags: javascript, frameworks, require, race-condition

We have a client-side plug-in framework that is constructed of modules (AMD) and utilizes require.js.  In this framework we expose a public object that consists of configuration properties and common framework functionality.  All of the required functionality for the public object is contained in one file (albeit separated into modules); the only file required by the end-user to add to their page.
The issue we are seeing is most prevalent in Safari but also shows itself occasionally in IE and Chrome.  100% of the time in Safari with an empty cache we encounter a race condition.  Consider this example client code which is in the body of the client’s page.

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    Me.subscribe(‘someEvent’, someHandler);
</script>
```

‘**Me**’ is always available to the page as its global and outside of any define call.  However, ‘**Me.subscribe**’ is wrapped in ‘**define**’ and results in ‘*undefined*’ with the conditions I stated above.
We can’t tell the client to use any third-party frameworks to work around this issue.  The code block above must stay exactly as it is.
I’ve been playing with the idea of allowing certain public function binding to be deferred without any additional work required by the client.  So far, this is what I’m considering adding to the framework:

```
Me.deferred = function (fn, name) {
            if (fn) return fn;
            fn = this;
            return function () {
                var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    fn[name].apply(this, args);
                }, 0);
            };
        };
```

Then, in the framework near the top, I can add items I want deferred like this:

```
Me.subscribe = Me.deferred(Me.subscribe,'subscribe');
```

My questions are these:  Am I missing something that is already out there?  Is there an existing pattern that I am not aware of to handle this exact case?  Is this just a bad idea in general?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, make sure the client puts `requireJS` and all dependencies in the [head](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/12/06/evolution-of-script-loading/). '**Me**' can include an [on-demand](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript) call which executes on creation if that is not possible.